# How to dispatch request to "j_spring_security_check" from controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Through `login.jsp` I needed some value, so I forwarded request to controller after this I want to dispatch to default `j_spring_security_check` from controller.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since /j_spring_security_check is handled in a filter you'll need to add an extra bit to your Spring Security filter mapping, for example:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

`<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` will allow you to forward the request from your controller.