# Spring Security - Dispatch to /j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring, servlets, post, spring-security

I have spring security in place and login via login.jsp works perfectly fine.

Now, I have to automatically get the user logged in based on the URL (similar to Single Sign On). I basically have a path parameter in the URL which is basically an encrypted code, I process this code to do an auto login.

I am modifying my LoginController to check if I have a valid path param using which I get my username & password, using this username & password I am doing `"forward:/j_spring_security_check?j_username="+username+"&j_password="+password`

This directs me to login.jsp with following error `Your login attempt was not successful, try again. Caused : Authentication method not supported: GET`

I have also tried with `"redirect:/j_spring_security_check?j_username="+username+"&j_password="+password` but with no help.

Call to `/j_spring_security_check` is a `POST` but `forward:` & `redirect:` is doing a `GET`, so how can I dispatch to `/j_spring_security_check` as `POST` from my LoginController?

Thanks

Comment: Check if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8229195/322166

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/j_spring_security_check` URL is mapped to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to serve the requests.

In `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, by default, the `postOnly` is set to `true`.

The following change in `spring-security.xml` which sets `postOnly` to `false` worked.

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter" 
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
      p:postOnly="false" />
```

Also, in `web.xml`, the following configuration is required:

```
<filter-mapping> <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could bypass the check by using a request wrapper which returns "POST" instead of "GET" for `getMethod`.

However, the check is there for a reason. It is generally considered bad practice to send credentials as URL parameters. Even if you are using an encrypted parameter, it is still technically equivalent to sending unencrypted authentication credentials since anyone who steals it can use it to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Right now I can think of no other alternative apart from directly invoking `/j_spring_security_check` with URL params, if you have one please do share.

Comment: The /j_spring_security_check isn't where the security problem lies. You could just as easily invoke the `AuthenticationManager` directly yourself rather than trying create a request to the form login filter (which is a bad idea, especially a redirect). However, sending the path parameter in the URL is probably not a good idea in the first place.