# Passing model attribute during redirect in spring MVC and avoiding the same in URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, redirect

My objective is to pass model attributes from controller to JSP page during a redirect and avoid the attribute being displayed in URL. The source code below is validating login from datastore using java data objects.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    int count;
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    //Instance of data class
        User user;
    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();

    @RequestMapping(value="/Login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginValidate(HttpServletRequest req){

        //Getting login values
        String uname=req.getParameter("nameLogin");
        String pswd1=req.getParameter("pswdLogin");
        count=0;


        user=new User();

        //Generating Query
        Query q = pm.newQuery(User.class);
        q.setFilter("userName == userNameParam");
        q.declareParameters("String userNameParam");

        try{
            List<User> results = (List<User>) q.execute(uname);  
            for (User u: results) {

                String userName=u.getUserName();

                if(userName.equals(uname)){

                    System.out.println(u.getPassword());

                    if(u.getPassword().equals(pswd1)){
                        count=count+1;
                        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:welcome");
                        modelAndView.addObject("USERNAME",uname);
                        return modelAndView;

                    }
         //rest of the logic 
    }
```

JSP:

```
 <h1>Welcome ${USERNAME} </h1>
```

My current URL is `/welcome?USERNAME=robin`
My goal is to display it as `/welcome` 
Also, my page is supposed to display "Welcome robin" whereas it displays only Welcome.

Comment: Not answering your question, just a note to your coding style. DB Querying in the controller is not nice. Access it from some userDAO via service. And even more important. It seems to me you are storing user's passwords as they are sent from client and dont hash them. That is extremely unsafe.

Comment: Yeah, i will change. I did this just for time being, to learn them. Will account it and change them. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544398/spring-security-dispatch-to-j-spring-security-check

Comment: I didn't use any spring-security.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

RedirectAttributes only work with RedirectView, please follow the same

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView loginValidate(HttpServletRequest req, RedirectAttributes redir){
...

    redirectView= new RedirectView("/foo",true);
    redir.addFlashAttribute("USERNAME",uname);
    return redirectView;
}
```

Those *flash attributes* are passed via the session (and are destroyed immediately after being used - see Spring Reference Manual for details). This has two interests :

- they are not visible in URL
- you are not restricted to String, but may pass arbitrary objects.

Comment: Landed with this new error "Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model."

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error under Spring 3.2. Could you give precisions, at least the line of the error and eventual causes ?

Comment: Error : Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.cd.racer.LoginController.loginValidate(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.

Comment: @cm1011 The answer is here : *You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument*. As you allready have `@Controller` annotation, your controller should be found by spring with only `<context:component-scan>` directive (if you are using xml config).

Comment: So you will have to say what version of spring you are using and to show you spring config (at least the part relative to the controller)

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1. <context:component-scan base-package="com.cd.racer"></context:component-scan><mvc:annotation-driven />

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with your original question. From `RequestMapping` javadoc : NOTE: Spring 3.1 introduced a new set of support classes for @RequestMapping methods in Servlet environments ... The new support classes are enabled by default from the MVC namespace and with use of the MVC Java config (@EnableWebMvc) but must be configured explicitly if using neither. Your current problem is *How to enable new support classes for @RequestMapping methods in Spring MCV 3.1*

Comment: yeah! Thanks for the response! Will check out

Comment: I can confirm that this solution solved the issue I was having. I had a redirect after an initial POST request, but needed to put a message onto the page. RedirectAttributes and setFlashAttribute worked like a charm

Comment: But how do you then access the values from the JSP page?

Answer (score 8):

You need to be careful here because I think what are you trying to do is not supported for a good reason. The **"redirect"** directive will issue a **GET** request to your controller. The **GET** request should only retrieve existing state using request parameters, this is the method contract. That ***GET*** request ***should not*** rely on a previous interaction or on any object stored some where in the session as a result of it. **GET** request is designed to retrieve existing (persisted) state. Your original (**POST**) request should have persisted everything you need for you **GET** request to retrieve a state.

**RedirectAttributes** are not designed to support you in this case, and even if you managed to correctly use it it will only work once and then they will be destroyed. If you then refresh the browser you will get an application error because it cannot find your attributes anymore.