# Spring Boot; passing user's First Name to welcome.jsp after logging in

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, crud

A lot of the articles online for Spring Boot deals with Spring Security and it does not help me in the slightest. I am trying to implement a registration and login page and once the user successfully logins, it will take them to a welcome page where it should display their first name, something like "Welcome first name or Welcome username". I have tried passing the first name through a
`model.addAttribute("firstName", accountInstance.getFirstName());`
but that doesn't seem to work. Any hints to achieve this would be much appreciated

**Login Controller**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("login", new AccountEntity());
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object submitLoginIn(@ModelAttribute("login") AccountEntity accountForm, Model model) {

        AccountEntity accountInstance = accountRepo.findByEmail(accountForm.getEmail().toLowerCase());

        // Password Verifier using Argon2
        Argon2PasswordEncoder argon2PasswordEncoder = new Argon2PasswordEncoder();
        boolean passwordMatch = argon2PasswordEncoder.matches(accountForm.getPassword(), accountInstance.getPassword());

        // issue where if i use caps email, throws null pointer exception
        if (accountInstance == null || !passwordMatch) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Email or Password");
            // return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
            return "login";
        } else if (accountInstance.isEnabled() == false) {
            System.out.println("Cant login cause not verified");
            return "login";
        } else {
            System.out.println("account exist");
            model.addAttribute("firstName", accountInstance.getFirstName());
            return "redirect:welcome"; // Change later
        }

    }
}
```

**Account Repository**

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<AccountEntity, Long> {
    // Optional<AccountEntity> findById(Long Id);
    AccountEntity findByUserName(String userName);

    AccountEntity findByPassword(String password);

    AccountEntity findByEmail(String email);

    AccountEntity findByVerificationCode(String verificationCode);
}
```

**Account Entity**

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class AccountEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    // private String gender;
    private Integer age;
    private Date createdDate;
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String verificationCode;

    // Getters and Setters
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /*
     * public String getGender() { return gender; }
     * 
     * public void setGender(String gender) { this.gender = gender; }
     */

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getVerificationCode() {
        return verificationCode;
    }

    public void setVerificationCode(String verificationCode) {
        this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<p> Welcome, ${firstName.firstName} </p>
<!-- <p> Welcome, ${firstName} </p> -->
```

Comment: Is there an exception you get? Can you please tell me the steps you take and what goes wrong exactly?

Comment: Hello! No exception, just no output on the JSP

Comment: Please give me a list of steps you take, still a little lost where the error happens :)

Comment: Well its not really an error, I just don't get an output; basically a user logins and I want the username that is associated with that email to appear on the screen but it doesn't

Comment: Should it be only firstName and not firstName.firstName. Can you debug through and check in the Controller if firstName is being set properly. Am assuming this is not a Spring Security issue rather a Spring issue around passing values to the jsp page. Is that right?

Comment: @Bollywood, You are correct on the Spring Security issue since I decided not to use spring security for the project. I tried both firstName.firstName and just firstName. As you can see in the AccountEntity.java, the variable is named firstName and I do believe that I set up the model.addAttribute correctly. I also did try login.firstName since the "@"ModelAttribute is ("login")

Comment: @Donobuz, I think it needs to be just firstName on the jsp as ${firstName} since you are adding a String attribute to the model and not the object itself. When you say no output on the JSP do you mean nothing after Welcome, ?. Try setting a hardcoded value and see if you can see that after Welcome.

Comment: @Donobuz sorry had a look again at your code. Why are you doing a redirect and not returning a ModelAndView. Returning a ModelAndView instead of doing a redirect should solve the issue. If you are using Redirect you would have to use a RedirectView and RedirectAttributes. Check this article out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301114/passing-model-attribute-during-redirect-in-spring-mvc-and-avoiding-the-same-in-u/24302616

Comment: @Bollywood, Thanks for taking the time to look at my code! I am doing a redirect:welcome since I thought redirecting would allow the welcome page to grab the passed variable. Since I am using a model structure instead of a ModelandView structure, i thought this was the most viable option; what would I potentially have to change to fix this? --.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO @Bollywood was correct with the redirecting:welcome. Doing so didn't pass the value I wanted to the jsp. Changing it to return "welcome" instead of return "redirect:welcome" worked!

Comment: Good that it worked and I could steer you in the right direction. I would suggest using thymeleaf if you are not already using it and I personally prefer returning ModelAndView instead of returning a String with the page name (although it seems ModelAndView might be old convention). This article outlines the differences between the 2 approaches - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988442/what-is-the-difference-between-return-modelandview-and-return-string-in-spring-m/25988589